# Yarn 2: Difference between Zero Installs and normal install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

Regarding Zero Installs, the Yarn 2 [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs) says:

> While not a feature in itself, the term "Zero Install" encompasses a lot of Yarn features tailored around one specific goal - to make your projects as stable and fast as possible by removing the main source of entropy from the equation: Yarn itself. [...]

I read the whole story, but didn't really understand that fully.

What is the difference between Yarn 2 Zero Installs and Yarn 2 normal install?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that using Yarn normal install, you won't need to commit the node_modules (all your deps), whereas, using Zero-Install you will have to take care of all your dependencies.

This certainly makes your dependency on remote repositories less, however, it requires more responsibility, as said in the docs:

> Note that, by design, this setup requires that you trust people
>   modifying your repository. In particular, projects accepting PRs from
>   external users will have to be careful that the PRs affecting the
>   package archives are legit (since it would otherwise be possible to a
>   malicious user to send a PR for a new dependency after having altered
>   its archive content).

After all, zero-install is a great feature. It solves the "I cloned/switched branch and now a dependency is missing" problem, it speeds up CI significantly and it lowers our dependence on our on-prem npm registry.

Comment: I would also add that it solves the problem of outdated dependencies. If you have a project which rarely updates, you can easily run into issues if one of the old dependencies becomes missing (e.g. removed by author, npm, etc.).